# Pyzo shortcut to go from editor window to shell

Tags: python, shortcuts

I am using [Pyzo](https://pyzo.org/) and I am looking for a shortcut to go from the editor window  to the shell.

Pyzo features state that within pyzo:

> Using an intuitive shortcut editor, a shortcut can be created for any item in the menu.

but I haven't find the way to do use this function.

Is anybody aware of such shortcut or the way one can create it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Using an intuitive shortcut editor, a shortcut can be created for any item in the menu."

It seems likely that this is referring to *Settings → Edit key mappings*.

> I am looking for a shortcut to go from the editor window to the shell.

You can use *View → Select Shell* (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> or alternately <kbd>F1</kbd>) to jump from the editor to the shell.

To jump from the shell to the editor use *View → Select Editor* (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> or alternately <kbd>F2</kbd>).

These shortcuts can both be edited under *Settings → Edit key mappings* by selecting the `View` tab in the *Shortcut mappings* dialog:

*ex. Shortcut Mappings Dialog*

[image]